# Youtube-dl downlaod from terminal but stop from java program (same command)

Tags: java, linux, terminal, youtube-dl

I manage to download embedded video from terminal but when I call it from java program is not working.

This is the code I use from java:

```
for(String url: referrerSet) {
        String command = "youtube-dl " + url;
        System.out.println(command);
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
        }
    }
```

`youtube-dl https://player.vimeo.com/video/2352345 --referer  'https://referrerUrl.html'`

When I execute from terminal

```
[vimeo] 2352345: Downloading webpage
[vimeo] 2352345: Extracting information
[vimeo] 2352345: Downloading JSON metadata
WARNING: Unable to download JSON metadata: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

and start to download the video when I run from java I see only this output:

```
[vimeo] 2352345: Downloading webpage
```

And skip to next link without downloading the video

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely solution is to use the full path of `youtube-dl`, so on Linux will probably be `/usr/bin/youtube-dl`. This is because `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` is actually running a file and not a bash shell.

If that doesn't fix your problem then you should also write the error stream of the process to the standard out and that will tell you the problem.

Comment: Is same with full path i already use youtube-dl for youtube videos from java and is working.I will see with error stream now

Comment: okay i found the problem it was youtube-dl https://player.vimeo.com/video/2352345 --referer  'https://reffererUrl.html' the ' ' in the referer link

Answer (score 0):

As ben said, you should use the full path. Programs are not always in the same /usr/bin/* folder. For future projects you should try to use `/usr/bin/bash -c "command here"`.